# Use .NET bundling & minification feature in angularjs - index.html

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a web site with angularjs framework for front-end using index.html and .net REST API services.

I need to achieve something one of followings:

**1.** I can create a dummy MVC view and write `@Scripts.Render(...)` to render all the bundled script and whatever I can see chrome developers tool e.g.

**`/bundles/angular?v=asIfVCRZ0mozQeQR34C1aw1HwLnnZATyODNO8bNn1mY1`** 
I can take this to index.html and put in a way

`<script src="/bundles/angular?v=asIfVCRZ0mozQeQR34C1aw1HwLnnZATyODNO8bNn1mY1"></script>`

**2.** This is possible on my local, however I am not sure, if I publish to another server, there random key **asIfVCRZ0mozQeQR34C1aw1HwLnnZATyODNO8bNn1mY1** will remain as is.

So questions here are:

1. Is there any setting to keep this key unchanged?
2. OR simply handling bundle & minification feature of angularjs-index.html page? **`note- I do not want to use any of npm packages`**

Comment: why not make your home page an MVC view (just Index), rather than a static .html? Then there's no problem. Angular will still work just the same, and the minification will work without you having to hardcode any links

Comment: I got something equivalent to this need using **web Essentials 2012**, where I can only bundle & minify my javascripts into a single file and refer that file into index.html. [**Refer here**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2013/11/05/making-web-development-wonderful-again-with-web-essentials/)

Comment: if you use MVC and just create one single JS bundle and one single CSS bundle in BundleConfig.cs containing all of your script/style files respectively, you'll get one single bundle download for each type. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Basically, I am not using MVC, however to get thsi dynamic key from somewhere I use dummy MVC view and `@Scripts.Render(...)`, so from Chrome development tool I can get dynamic key. However need make sure this remains same across multiple environments.

Comment: which is why I'm saying why not just actually make your home page an MVC view, instead of messing about making "dummy" views and then trying to re-use the minified scripts elsewhere? I think you're making it more complicated than it needs to be. What's the reason _not_ to use an MVC view for a single page app?